# how to read the following structure in django,python

Tags: python, django, templates, dictionary, tuples

```
(

{'locker__city': u'Old Delhi', 'locker__state': u'Delhi', 'locker__locker_name': u'BI', 'day5': 50L, 'locker__pincode': u'110096'}, 

{'locker__city': u'Old Delhi', 'locker__state': u'Delhi', 'locker__locker_name': u'BI', 'day2': 50L, 'locker__pincode': u'110096'}

)
```

I have the following data structure to read and access in python. I am really new to the language. Can anyone helpme out as to how could i print the value of "Locker__city" and other fields and print in django templates.

Answer (score 0):

**View**

```
data = (
   {
      'locker__city': u'Old Delhi',
      'locker__state': u'Delhi',
      'locker__locker_name': u'BI',
      'day5': 50L,
      'locker__pincode': u'110096'
   },
   {
      'locker__city': u'Old Delhi',
      'locker__state': u'Delhi',
      'locker__locker_name': u'BI',
      'day2': 50L,
      'locker__pincode': u'110096'
   }
)

def some_view(request):
   context = {'data': data}
   return render(request, 'path/to/template.html', context)
```

**template.html**

```
{% for i in data %}
   {{ i.locker__city }}
{% endfor %}
```